# (IE BHO) Get IWebBrowser2 from BeforeNavigate2 event

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, bho, iwebbrowser2

I'm working on an IE BHO, in the BeforeNavigate2 event, how can I get the pointer to IWebBrowser2?  here's my code:

```
STDMETHODIMP CEventSink::Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, .....) {
    IWebBrowser2* pSite = 0;
    HRESULT hr;

if(dispIdMember == DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2) {

    hr = ((IDispatch*)pDispParams->rgvarg[0].pdispVal)->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&pSite);// This line Crashes
```

and the type of param[0] isn't VT_DISPATCH:

```
if(pDispParams->rgvarg[0].vt == VT_DISPATCH) {
    msgbox("yes VT_DISPATCH");
} else {
    msgbox("no.."); // it goes here
}
```

the [MSDN (BeforeNavigate2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768280%28VS.85%29.aspx) says the first parameter is

> A pointer to the IDispatch interface for the WebBrowser object that represents the window or frame. This interface can be queried for the IWebBrowser2 interface.

What's wrong with my code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Invoke` implementation, the arguments are in reverse order.

Use `rgvarg[6]` for the "first" arguments, and use `rgvarg[0]` for the last one (the seventh)